# Making an enemy that shoots bullets in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a platform game and it has a level where there is a bullet being fired constantly in the same direction at the player. However, I can get 1 bullet to fire but I can't add more bullets to the list to fire repeatedly in constant intervals. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

            self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/bullet.png")
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = x
            self.rect.y = y

        def update(self):
            self.rect.y += 4

            if self.rect.y > 520:
                BulletList.empty()

    def main3():
        moveX = 0
        TrapList.empty()

        player.rect.x,player.rect.y = 50,0
        BulletList.add(bullet)
        FiringBullet = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
        pygame.time.set_timer(FiringBullet, 3000)

        GameExit = False

        while GameExit==False:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.move(-player.speed,0)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.move(player.speed,0)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move(0,-10)

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.move(player.speed,0)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.move(-player.speed,0)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move(0,0)

                if event.type == FiringBullet:
                    BulletList.add(bullet)
            print(BulletList)

            screen.fill(BLACK)
            level3.update()

            if player.rect.x > 350:
                for eachbullet in BulletList:
                    BulletList.draw(screen)
                    BulletList.update()


            playergroup.update()
            playergroup.draw(screen)

            player.Level3PlatColl(BlockListDirt2)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
        bullet = Bullets(400,200)
        BulletList = pygame.sprite.Group()
main3()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you fire you have to create new bullet instance.

```
if event.type == FiringBullet:

    bullet = Bullets(400,200) # new instance with own position

    BulletList.add(bullet) # suggestion to use lower_case name for variables
```

Now you use one instance. You add it to the list and you have many elements on list but all elements have the same position. If you change position of one of them then you change position of all of them.

see visualisation on PythonTutor.com (it is long link with python code)

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%0Abullets_list+%3D+%5B%5D%0A%0Abullet+%3D+(400,200%29%0A%0Abullets_list.append(bullet%29%0Abullets_list.append(bullet%29%0Abullets_list.append(bullet%29%0A%0A%23+----%0A%0Aother_list+%3D+%5B%5D%0A%0Abullet+%3D+(400,200%29%0Aother_list.append(bullet%29%0A%0Abullet+%3D+(400,200%29%0Aother_list.append(bullet%29%0A%0Abullet+%3D+(400,200%29%0Aother_list.append(bullet%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=12

---

**BTW:**

I would rather use name `Bullet` - it is single bullet position.

There is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) document (Style Guide for Python Code) which suggests

- lower_case names for variables - `bullet_list`, `trap_list`, `game_exit`
- UPPER_CASE names for constants - `FIRING_BULLET`
- CamelCase names for class - `Bullet`, `Sprite`, `Group`

Even Stackoverflow Editor treads CamelCase names as class names and use blue color for them.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this and your help in general! im doing this for a university project as a major python noob so thanks for ur support!